# CspParameter check if a keycontainername already exists

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I've successfully signed my XML files using the RSACryptoServiceProvider. My key is stored in the Machine Key Store.

Now, I would like to check if the machinekeystore already contains the key that is related with the keycontainername or if the rsacryptoserviceprovider will need to create a new one.

How may I accomplish this?

Appreciate for your help!
Camille.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Key Storage and Retrieval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), when Windows creates a Machine key store, it creates a file in the `Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\Machine Keys` directory.  You could loop through the files and search for the file. See the example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/f7b9f928-a794-47f2-a5bd-9f64ca375040) called `TryKeyContainerPermissionCheck` for a way you might find the file.

Comment: Appreciate for your answer, unfortunately there is no way to define what key in this directory is the key I've created... How to do that?